# how to hide tab 1 content when clicking other tabs Joomla Custom Component

Tags: tabs, joomla3.0

I have an edit view wherein I need to add a Tab for the Report's Line Item (fields). The first tab is the Report's Edit form. I want to create a list in the 2nd tab.

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_reports&layout=edit&id=' . (int) $this->item->id); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="adminForm" id="newreport-form" class="form-validate">

<div class="form-horizontal">

    <!-- Tab Initialization -->
    <?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.startTabSet', 'myTab', array('active' => 'general')); ?>
    <!-- here is my 1st tab -->

    <?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.addTab', 'myTab', 'general', JText::_($this->item->title. '`s details', true)); ?>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span10 form-horizontal">
            <fieldset class="adminform">

                                <input type="hidden" name="jform[id]" value="<?php echo $this->item->id; ?>" />
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('title'); ?></div>
            <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('title'); ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('isactive'); ?></div>
            <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('isactive'); ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('description'); ?></div>
            <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('description'); ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('created_by'); ?></div>
            <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('created_by'); ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('modified_by'); ?></div>
            <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('modified_by'); ?></div>
        </div>

        <?php
            foreach((array)$this->item->modified_by as $value): 
                if(!is_array($value)):
                    echo '<input type="hidden" class="modified_by" name="jform[modified_byhidden]['.$value.']" value="'.$value.'" />';
                endif;
            endforeach;
        ?>          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('date_created'); ?></div>
            <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('date_created'); ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('date_modified'); ?></div>
            <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('date_modified'); ?></div>
        </div>


            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>

   <!-- here is my 2nd tab -->
   <?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.addTab', 'myTab', 'fields', JText::_('Fields', true)); ?>



    <?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.endTab'); ?>

    <?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.endTabSet'); ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />
    <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>

</div>
```

Everything is fine but when I click the 2nd tab, the form in tab 1 is still displaying. What am I doing wrong? I just want that when I click the 2nd tab, the form in tab 1 is hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer myself.

I just need to add this code for every tab that I add:

```
<?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.endTab'); ?>
```